# confirmation popup on place order button

Tags: magento-1.7, theme

I want to add confirmation popup on place order button at final check out step.The flow is like

```
if (click on I understood){
   //then proceed
} 
else{
   //cancel
}
```

I tried to add simple jquery and calling it on onclick event bit it is not working.

need help asap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you have to edit your `chekout.js` file.

`skin\frontend\base\default\js\checkout.js`

At Line No 900 you find

```
save: function(){
  var data=confirm("click on I understood!");
  if (data==true)
  {
      // your code for by default checkout.provide.
  }
  else
  {
     //if not then your code.
  }
}
```

Hope you got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late, but for anyone looking for this, the solution offered is terrible. Prototype actually offers a way to 'extend' existing functions.

Since the 'Place Order' button triggers the Review.save()-function, you can extend it using wrap() as follows:

Within your custom module, add a block or js_item from your layout XML file (as long as its loaded after `opcheckout.js`) and do the following:

```
Review.prototype.save = Review.prototype.save.wrap(function(save) {
    // Do whatever you like, and if you want to call the parent method just call:
    save();
});
```

That's it! A way cleaner (not overriding or editing core files) approach.